# Batch: Write to a same log file from multiple instances of cmd

Tags: windows, multithreading, batch-file, cmd

Hello friends :) Well first I'll tell you the current situation and then the problem.

::SITUATION::

I have a batch file that starts a separate instance of cmd and a psexec connection for each of the listed hostnames/IPs on the computerList.txt file.

```
FOR /F %%i in (computerList.txt) DO (
start cmd /k "PsExec \\%%i -s cmd /c \\server\Commands.bat >> %LOGFILEpath%"
)
```

It passes out as parameter the bat file that contains all the commands I want the computer to run. It locally saves on each computer some data to variables, then simply call with "echo" to all that variables in a format like csv, say:

```
echo %date%,%time%,%hostname%,%outputOfTheMainCommand%
```

That line should be written to the log file, so that I can open it as csv with excel and easily have a decent report made.

::PROBLEM::

The process I described above, capturing the output of each execution to the logfile has been simple when looping the computerList.txt with a single instance. My "innovation" at this point is now to start multiple instances to do the same thing so that I can save much more time.

The problem lives in the fact that just the first computer makes it to write the file. in all the other instance windows I get the message that the logfile is in use so I cant write the output to it.

Is there a way to redirect the output of all the instances to a single log file? How should I do this? I was thinking to get the outputs of instances captured first by the parent batch (in a variable array or something) and then sent them all to the logfile, but I dont know how to do that.

Any help? Thank you so much!

Comment: Exit the individual processes as soon as they write to the log file using `exit`, that way the lock on the log file would be released. Check if this works for you...

Comment: It's not nice; if they could open the same file, you would get them all fighting to write over each other like "computer1 workCOMPUTER2outpu COMPing outpCOMPUTER5workCOM" and all mixed up things. Have them write to one log for each computer `%LOGFILEpath%-%%i.log` or similar, and then afterwards merge them all into one logfile if you need to with `copy` (see `copy /?` section "To append files")

Comment: Ok writing a logfile for each execution, then appending them all to a single file, then deleting the temporary logfiles seems to work :) At this point I have to wait until all the threads finish, then run a second bat to do the appending. Any idea of how can I make the original parent program to wait until all threads finished then build the final log? Thanks!